# Excel: I have a Data Validation List in one cell and I would like the selected value to change based on the value in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

My specific issue is this:

Cell I66 has a data validation list that has values such as "NOT STARTED", "N/A", "OVERDUE", etc.  The default is "NOT STARTED"

However, if there is a "N" in cell G3, I would like I66 value to change to "N/A"

Is there a way to accomplish this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of without macros, comes with a caveat. If you have a range (say A1=Not Started, A2= N/A, and A3=Overdue) with your options. You could, in the data validation window, use `=IF($G$3="N",$A$2,$A$1:$A$3)` 
That wont update the cell automatically, but it will update the option list to show nothing but N/A if G3=N, otherwise the data validation will allow all the options. This may be good enough for you, if G3 contains the value prior to picking from your data validated cell.
This should still work if you put your option list on another sheet, you'd just have to update the ranges in the formula to include the sheet name.